# What is the capacitance and/or inductance of a single straight piece of copper wire?

Tags: capacitance

What is the capacitance and/or inductance of a single straight piece of copper wire?   I know the answer is on Wiki, but I need for the answer to be supported.  I know that Wiki provides references, but I can not get to the references.  I am don't have access to the IEEE data base or any other such scholarly database or web site.  I actually need a scholarly paper or text book reference such as by J.D. Jackson.  I have been out of school for a long time (3 years) and I am still trying to finalize my thesis without having the needed reference resources.

Comment: What did you find on wiki/google that is not suitable or substantiated. This might be a useful start for anyone answering your question. Regarding capacitance, it will have zero capacitance - it only has capacitance in relation to another object such as ground so detail is required here from you.

Comment: @Andyaka: Every conductive object has some amount of "free space" capacitance, which is evaluated by pretending that the other plate is an infinitely-large sphere.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes I know but this capacitance can be extremely small for a thin wire of unknown length - I'm trying to get the op to think about what he's asking.

Comment: I believe the inductance calculation can be obtained from “Inductance Calculations” , F. W. Grover, Dover Publications, 2004.  I see a couple of online calculators based on this reference such as http://www.eeweb.com/toolbox/wire-inductance

Comment: @Andyaka: You're not helping him by making statements that you know are false. Clearly, he wants to calculate what that capacitance is, and stating that it's zero is completely misleading.

Comment: It is not that wiki is not substantiated.  It is that I do not have access to the documents which wiki point to and I need these documents.

Comment: Got a link to the wiki article?  I always go to Terman's "Radio Engineers' Handbook" for this type of thing.  I see some online sources, but I assume the pdf is huge.

Comment: Wait...so you have some homework and the professor won't let you use Wikipedia as a reference, so you thought you'd ask a bunch of random people on the internet, and use *that* as a reference? I think you are missing the point...

Comment: @Phil - no, the quest is not for random internet personalities to *be* references, but rather to *point to* references which are obtainable (and presumably evaluatable by traditional means)

Comment: You don't need the documents that the wiki points to. What for? As long as you trust the wiki's authors, you're all set. You merely need to put the same reference into your thesis, that's all. Alas, you're looking for sources that are too esoteric. Your local library system should have some electromagnetic texts.  They will have the equations you need. Heck, my high school physics textbook had them.

Comment: How are we to know if the references we give are more accessible (to you) than the ones in Wikipedia?

Comment: Anyway, any first-year E.M. textbook should cover this. I used Ramo, Whinnery, and Van Duzer, but you could cite whichever one you have on hand.

Comment: you don't really need to cite anything on IEEE for such a thing. I'd dare to say that depending on the paper angle and subject you can probably write down the equations without any citation. Or you're going to cite Newton everytime you make a derivative?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because paper recommendation questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for inductance of a straight piece of wire is given in the following link which also includes references:

http://chemandy.com/calculators/round-wire-inductance-calculator.htm

Comment: A link-only answer is dangerous because the link could be changed tomorrow and leave the answer with no value. It would be better if you could summarize the important content within the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in this document http://k9axn.com/_mgxroot/page_10920.html

The equation is in two forms, one in CM and one in feet.  The formatting for CM and feet is on page 585 and both equations on 586 for vertical and horizontal wires.

A pre calculated and the K factor chart are on P.609.  It is a simple formula to use.

Note on the pre calculated chart that the height above ground makes far less difference than most think.

As for the inductance formulas, you will find on WIKO, several different equations.  If you are working with antennas and displacement current, you need to define your intent because the inductance and capacitance in an antenna or transmission line combine to appear as non reactive impedance.

Regards Jim

Comment: While it is perfectly fine to reference your own website, please note that you **must** disclose your affiliation in your answers. See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior